# Is it possible to mount FSx storage on a Fargate windows containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to figure out if I can use Fargate for our app. As it uses a network storage, we decided to use FSx. However, I am unable to find a documentation on AWS on how to mount an FSx storage on a Fargate windows container. Is it possible?

I have only found this AWS article on how to mount FSx storage on [ECS EC2 container](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-as-persistent-storage-on-windows-containers/) host.

Could somebody confirm if FSx on Fargate windows containers is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for now it is not supported. FSx documentation mentions this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/wfsx-volumes.html

```
You cannot use FSx for Windows File Server volumes in a Windows containers on Fargate configuration.
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the confirmation! I have definitely missed this on the AWS docs.